# Flutter + Cloud firestore + Closures: Why can I print the document to the console, but not add to a list?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-async

So I've got a pretty complex Function with a lot of closures.

I am using Cloud Firestore for retrieving some userIds and after that I try to get the userData from Cloud Firestore.

The problem happens in the last Line of the following Code:

```
List matchList = List();

await CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'getUserIdsForSomePurpose',).call(<String, dynamic>{'userId': 'RANDOMUSERID'}).then(
     (result) => result.data.forEach(
            (matchId) async => await Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('id', isEqualTo: matchId.toString()).getDocuments().then(
                   (matchQuery) => matchList.add(matchQuery.documents[0].data.toString()))));
```

Even if I try to print the length of `matchList`, I get the following error:

```
E/flutter ( 6156): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter ( 6156): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:147:60)
E/flutter ( 6156): #1      MatchLogic.loadEventsIntoList (package:nsome/App/Matching/MatchLogic.dart:18:20)
```

If I change the last Line of the upper Code to the following (e.g. I print the data into the Console), it somehow works and I get all the data written to the Console:

```
(matchQuery) => print(matchQuery.documents[0].data.toString()))));
```

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem when I was creating my flutter app. Although I can't really explain why, but here is my solution:

```
    List matchList = List();


              _createNewFunction (List matchList) {
                await CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'getUserIdsForSomePurpose',).call(<String, dynamic>{'userId': 'RANDOMUSERID'}).then(
                     (result) => result.data.forEach(
                            (matchId) async => await Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('id', isEqualTo: matchId.toString()).getDocuments().then(
                                   (matchQuery) => matchList.add(matchQuery.documents[0].data.toString()))));
                }

    // run newly created function when you want to use it
    _createNewFunction(matchList);


print(matchList.length)  // should != 0 (if data is added successfully)
```

so instead of adding into the list inside the 'then' function, pass the 'matchList' into a newly created function as argument. This should probably work  :)

Comment: Apparently it didn't work. I still have the same behaviour :/